# Displaying a custom name for a host

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-inventory

I have an Ansible play-book for working with EC2 instances. I'm using dynamic inventory ([ec2.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/plugins/inventory/ec2.py)) to get the group of instances that I want to work with (`hosts: tag_Service_Foo`). When I run it, it produces output like:

```
GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [54.149.9.198]
ok: [52.11.22.29]
ok: [52.11.0.3]
```

However, I can fetch the "Name" tag for a particular instance from Amazon (I do this and store it in a variable for use in a couple parts of the playbook).

Is there a way to get Ansible to use this string for the hostname when displaying progress? I'd like to see something more descriptive (since I don't have the IPs memorized):

```
GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
ok: [main-server]
ok: [extra-server]
ok: [my-cool-server]
```

The output of the `ec2.py` inventory script looks like this (truncated; it's very long).

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "54.149.9.198": {
        "ec2__in_monitoring_element": false,
        "ec2_ami_launch_index": "0",
        "ec2_architecture": "x86_64",
        "ec2_client_token": "xxx",
        "ec2_dns_name": "xxx",
        "ec2_ebs_optimized": false,
        "ec2_eventsSet": "",
        "ec2_group_name": "",
        "ec2_hypervisor": "xen",
        "ec2_id": "i-xxx",
        "ec2_image_id": "ami-xxx",
        "ec2_instance_type": "xxx",
        "ec2_ip_address": "xxx",
        "ec2_item": "",
        "ec2_kernel": "",
        "ec2_key_name": "xxx",
        "ec2_launch_time": "xxx",
        "ec2_monitored": xxx,
        "ec2_monitoring": "",
        "ec2_monitoring_state": "xxx",
        "ec2_persistent": false,
        "ec2_placement": "xxx",
        "ec2_platform": "",
        "ec2_previous_state": "",
        "ec2_previous_state_code": 0,
        "ec2_private_dns_name": "xxx",
        "ec2_private_ip_address": "xxx",
        "ec2_public_dns_name": "xxx",
        "ec2_ramdisk": "",
        "ec2_reason": "",
        "ec2_region": "xxx",
        "ec2_requester_id": "",
        "ec2_root_device_name": "/dev/xvda",
        "ec2_root_device_type": "ebs",
        "ec2_security_group_ids": "xxx",
        "ec2_security_group_names": "xxx",
        "ec2_sourceDestCheck": "true",
        "ec2_spot_instance_request_id": "",
        "ec2_state": "running",
        "ec2_state_code": 16,
        "ec2_state_reason": "",
        "ec2_subnet_id": "subnet-xxx",
        "ec2_tag_Name": "main-server",
        "ec2_tag_aws_autoscaling_groupName": "xxx",
        "ec2_virtualization_type": "hvm",
        "ec2_vpc_id": "vpc-xxx"
      }
    }
  }
  "tag_Service_Foo": [
    "54.149.9.198",
    "52.11.22.29",
    "52.11.0.3"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this (aliasing) at runtime or statically? Static can be done via inventory file very easily.

Comment: Edited my question. I'm using dynamic inventory with the ec2.py script.

Comment: Can you post the output (part of it) of `ec2.py` when you run it on command line like `python ec2.py` or `./ec2.py`?

Comment: Added. Looking more carefully at the output, I see that I actually have a variable `ec2_tag_Name` available to me for each host. So I don't need to do so much work fetching tags. That's nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create your own wrapper (say `my_ec2.py`) over the `ec2.py` that would post process the output. Idea is to use the [behavioral hostvar `ansible_ssh_host`](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters). You can use any language not only python. As long as it prints valid json on stdout you're good to go. [Reference if needed](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_inventory.html).

It'll be a tiny bit of work. But hope the sudo code would help:

```
output_json_map = new map
for each group in <ec2_output>: # e.g. tag_Service_Foo, I think there would be another 
                                # key in the output that contains list of group names.
  for each ip_address in group:
    hname = ec2_output._meta.hostvars.find(ip_address).find(ec2_tag_Name)

    # Add new host to the group member list
    output_json_map.add(key=group, value=hname)
    copy all vars from ec2_output._meta.hostvars.<ip_address>
                  to output_json_map._meta.hostvars.<hname>
    # Assign the IP address of this host to the ansible_ssh_host
    # in hostvars for this host
    output_json_map.add(key=_meta.hostvars.<hname>.ansible_ssh_host,
                        value=ip_address)
    output_json_map.add(key=_meta.hostvars.find(ip_address).ansible_ssh_host,
                        value=ip_address)

print output_json_map to stdout
```

**E.g. for your example the output of `my_ec2.py` should be:**

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "main-server": {
        "ansible_ssh_host": "54.149.9.198"
        --- snip ---
        "ec2_tag_Name": "main-server",
        --- snip ---
      },
      "extra-server": {
        "ansible_ssh_host": "52.11.22.29"
        --- snip ---
        "ec2_tag_Name": "extra-server",
        --- snip ---
      },
      <other hosts from all groups>
    }
  }
  "tag_Service_Foo": [
    "main-server",
    "extra-server",
    <other hosts in this group>
  ],
  "some other group": [
    <hosts in this group>,
    ...
  ],
}
```

and obviously, use this `my_ec2.py` instead of `ec2.py` as the inventory file. :-)

**-- edit --**

> 1) In the groups, can I only refer to things by one name? 2) There's
>   no notion of an alias? 3) I'm wondering if I could use the IP addr in
>   the groups and just modify the _meta part or if I need to do it all?

Yes*, No and no.

---

* Technically first yes should be no. Let me explain.

What we are doing here can be done with static inventory file like this:

Original `ec2.py` was returning json equivalent of following inventory file:

```
[tag_Service_Foo]
54.149.9.198 ec2_tag_Name="main-server"  ec2_previous_state_code="0" ...
52.11.22.29  ec2_tag_Name="extra-server" ec2_previous_state_code="0" ...
```

our new `my_ec2.py` returns this:

```
[tag_Service_Foo]
main-server  ansible_ssh_host="54.149.9.198" ec2_tag_Name="main-server"  ec2_previous_state_code="0" ...
extra-server ansible_ssh_host="52.11.22.29"  ec2_tag_Name="extra-server" ec2_previous_state_code="0" ...

# Technically it's possible to create "an alias" for main-server like this:
main-server-alias  ansible_ssh_host="54.149.9.198" ec2_tag_Name="main-server"  ec2_previous_state_code="0" ...
```

Now you would be able to run a play with `main-server-alias` in the host list and ansible would execute it on `54.149.9.198`.

**BUT**, and this is a big BUT, when you run a play with 'all' as the host pattern ansible would run the task on `main-server-alias` as well as `main-server`. So what you created is an alias in one context and a new host in another. I've not tested this **BUT part** so do come back and correct me if you find out otherwise.

HTH

Comment: In the groups, can I only refer to things by one name? There's no notion of an alias? (I'm wondering if I could use the IP addr in the groups and just modify the `_meta` part or if I need to do it all.)

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot not sure if you get an update when I update the answer so: See the updated answer.

Comment: No, I don't get alerts on edits to an answer. Thanks for such a detailed answer! I'll try this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
vpc_destination_variable = Name
```

in your `ec2.ini` file, that should work too.

Answer (score 1):

For a more recent version, working since version 2.9 of Ansible, at least, the `aws_ec2` plugin now allows this as a simple configuration, without the need to create any warper around *ec2.py*.

This can be done using a combination of the parameters [`hostnames`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html#parameter-hostnames) and [`compose`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html#parameter-compose).

So the trick is to change the name of the EC2 instance via the `hostnames` parameter to have something human readable — for example from an AWS tag on the instance — and then to use the `compose` parameter to set the `ansible_host` to the `private_ip_address`, `public_ip_address`, `private_dns_name` or the `public_dns_name` to allow the connection, still.

Here would be the minimal configuration of the plugin to allow this:

```yaml
plugin: aws_ec2
hostnames:
  - tag:Name 
  # ^-- Given that you indeed have a tag named "Name" on your EC2 instances
compose:
  ansible_host: public_dns_address
```

---

Mind, that, in AWS, the tags are not uniques, so you can have multiple instances tagged with the same name, but in Ansible, the hostname *is something unique*. This means that you will probably be better of composing the name with the `tag:Name` postfixing with something truly unique, like the instance ID.

Something like:

```yaml
plugin: aws_ec2
hostnames:
  - name: 'instance-id'
    separator: '_'
    prefix: 'tag:Name'
compose:
  ansible_host: public_dns_address
```