# Endpoint from aws_rds plugin - Ansible

Tags: ansible, amazon-rds

I'm using aws_rds plugin to create an inventory with my rds cluster/instances and create groups_vars based on the environment tags.

```yaml
plugin: aws_rds
regions:
  - xx-xxxx-x
include_clusters: true
keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.Environment
    prefix: "tag_Environment_"
    separator: ""
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/inventory/aws_rds.html

The problem is that this plugin doesn't allow to take the Endpoint name so I was wondering if it's possible to add the last part of this `cluster-xxxxxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com` on each group_var created, like `ansible_host= ${ansible_host}.cluster-xxxxxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com` or something like that.

Comment: _Disclaimer: I don't have a RDS cluster under my hand to test it, hence why this is a comment_. Based on an educated guess on the EC2 inventory plugin I would test, under a [`compose`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/inventory/aws_rds.html#parameter-compose) key to add `ansible_host: endpoint`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I'm going to try it, although I'm not very familiar with jinja. Do you have any examples to guide me?

Comment: There is no jinja involved. Just a plain YAML in the inventory with `compose:` and one line under, indented, `ansible_host: endpoint`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I have added it, but it still shows the db ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I achieved what I wanted by defining this variable in groups_vars (so I could define one for each environment).

```
ansible_host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}.cluster-xxxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Those AWS inventory plugin are gathering a lot of information from the API, I had quite a similar requirement lately on [`aws_ec2` inventory plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69667755/2123530) and here is how I proceeded to find the information I needed under the [`compose`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/plugins/inventory/aws_rds.html#parameter-compose) parameter of the inventory's configuration.

1. To fetch what I needed to put under the `compose` parameter, I first configured the inventory, like you did.
2. Then I displayed all the collected hosts, using

   ```sh
   ansible-inventory --graph
   ```

   This yields something like

   ```
   @all:
     |--@nodes:
     |  |--node1
     |  |--node2
     |  |--node3
     |--@ungrouped:
   ```
3. With this, I targeted one node, let's say `node1`, here, and I displayed all the information Ansible had on them, doing:

   ```sh
   ansible -m setup node1
   ```

   and

   ```sh
   ansible -m debug -a "var=vars" node1
   ```
4. In all this, in searched for the information needed.
   In your case that could be achieved by doing:

   ```sh
   ansible -m setup <one-of-the-hosts> | grep "cluster-" | grep ".rds.amazonaws.com"
   ```

   and

   ```sh
   ansible -m debug -a <one-of-the-hosts> | grep "cluster-" | grep ".rds.amazonaws.com"
   ```
5. Last but not least, configured the variable I found out in the `compose` parameter of the inventory's configuration

   ```yaml
   compose:
     ansible_host: <variable-name-found-at-step-4>
   ```

   e.g., in my EC2 configuration, it ended up being `public_dns_address`

   ```yaml
   plugin: aws_ec2
   hostnames:
     - tag:Name 
     # ^-- Given that you indeed have a tag named "Name" on your EC2 instances
   compose:
     ansible_host: public_dns_address
   ```

Comment: would have worked, but it had the extra complexity of an ssh tunnel to reach the instances, etc. In the end, I opted for something more basic like:

`ansible_host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}.cluster-xxxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com"`

thank you!